# TypeError: Greeter.deployed(...).greet is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache

Getting error
Code:

```
  address payable owner;
  constructor ()  
  {
    owner= payable(msg.sender);
  }
  function kill() public
  {
    if(msg.sender== owner)
    {selfdestruct(owner);}

  }
}

contract greeter is mortal{
  string greeting;
  constructor (string memory _greeting) {
    greeting = _greeting;
  }
  function setGreeting (string memory _greeting) public {
    greeting = _greeting;
    
  }
  function greet() public view returns (string memory)
  {
    return greeting;    
  }
}
```

[image: Console]

Comment: It looks like the issue is in the truffle code. Can you share the truffle javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Per truffle docs, the `.at` functionality will yield a Promise. Based on what you're querying inside the terminal, shouldn't the syntax be more like:

```
(await greeter.at(address)).greet()
```

Comment: It is giving this error 
Uncaught ReferenceError: address is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:21
but greeter.address gives the address output

Comment: There are some previous posts regarding this. Some fixes involve running migrate after starting the truffle console. Or downgrading but can you try running migrate first?

https://github.com/trufflesuite/trufflesuite.com/issues/737
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694212/truffle-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined-after-using-migrate

Answer (score 0):

thank you for mentioning to add await...
don't forget to add async to your functions
ie.

```
module.exports = async function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(greeter, 'Hi Hello', { gas: 6700000 });
};
```